# does minHeight do anything?

Tags: android, layout

In the attached image, I want the column of buttons to match the height of the image, but I also want there to be a minimum height for the column of buttons.

It correctly matches the height of the image, but does not respect the minHeight, and will smoosh the buttons down.

I am setting these properties for the column of buttons:

```
<LinearLayout
   ...
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
   android:minHeight="150dp"
   >
```

[image]

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I don't know all your exact requirements, but it seems you can solve this with another layer pretty much like in your diagram. Set the `minHeight` on an outer layout and then just `fill_parent`/`match_parent` on the inside. Maybe something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="150dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But remember: if you use to many layouts your app might become sluggish at startup. It seems that layouts need a lot of memory at startup which might trigger garbage collection slowing down your app until the memory needed for startup has been freed again. And yes, I have that problem and currently I try to switch to RelativLayout instead.

Answer (score 10):

Tricky question because it calls [TextView.setMinHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMinHeight(int)) — but then you are not using a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

So generally `android:minHeight` does indeed do something but not in your particular case.

Comment: This was a good answer to the original question asked. It probably doesn't help the user achieve their end goal, but I found it interesting nonetheless.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. minHeight in general for views is a valid attribute. Its programatic equivalent is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMinimumHeight(int)

Comment: @David Liu That the attribute is valid in the XML doesn't mean that it is stored in the view. 

And even when the attribute is stored in the view it doesn't mean that is is actually used by the active layout manager.

And to make it even more fun: there is a `TextView.setMinHeight` and a `View.setMinimumHeight`

Comment: The point is that bringing up TextView.setMinHeight is completely irrelevant, because the question doesn't ask about text views. As for the validity of the XML, it's clearly used and stored in the base View class, as seen here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java line 970. Whether or not it is actually used by the active layout manager is irrelevant to my point (though as seen in the accepted answer, that minHeight attribute was relevant to the actual answer, as LinearLayout **does** take into account View.minHeight).

Answer (score 2):

Although my other answer is still valid, nowadays we have the benefit of [`ConstraintLayout`](https://constraintlayout.com/). I'm sure the original poster has long since gotten past this problem, but for future users' sake: you can achieve the same result without the extra layer of `ViewGroup`s. Something like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="150dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button1,button2,button3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Possibly you may need something like:

```
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

for the `ImageView` to handle larger images, but I haven't tested it.