# setMinimumHeight() on LinearLayout isn't working (in subclass)

Tags: java, android

I have a subclass of a liner layout (referenced from XML custom type) The minimum height I've tried to set just isn't working nor is setting the layout. I need to do this programatically...

Why isn't setMinimumHeight() working?

NB: The complexity of the code can be ignored, the value it is setting is 70

```
public class SummaryDynamicSpacer extends LinearLayout {

    private static final String TAG = "mymeter-DynamicSpacer";
    int dpWidth = 0;
    int dpHeight = 0;

    public SummaryDynamicSpacer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public SummaryDynamicSpacer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        //Set dpWidth, this is the key metric we use for scaling.
        float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dpWidth  = metrics.widthPixels / density;
        float dpHeight  = metrics.heightPixels / density;
        this.dpWidth = (int)dpWidth;
        this.dpHeight = (int)dpHeight;

        Log.d(TAG, "zyxHeightDP: "+metrics.heightPixels / density);

        int id = this.getId();
        int increment = 10;
        int adjustment = getValueForLargeDevice(increment);


        if(id == R.id.betweenAddressAndTopBox) {
            doBetweenAddressAndTopBox(context, adjustment);
        } else if(id == R.id.betweenTopAndAddress) {
            doBetweenTopAndAddress(context, adjustment);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "SettingHeight: "+adjustment);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    private void doBetweenAddressAndTopBox(Context context, int adjustment) {
        this.setMinimumHeight(adjustment);
    }

    private void doBetweenTopAndAddress(Context context, int adjustment) {
        this.setMinimumHeight(adjustment);
    }

    private int getValueForLargeDevice(double increment) {
        int largeDeviceAdjustment = 0;
        if(dpHeight > 750) {
            int difference = (int)dpHeight - 750;
            int interval = 25;
            int iterations =  (difference / interval) > 12 ? 12 : (difference / interval);
            int increasePerInterval = 0;
            for(int i=0; i < iterations; i++) {
                largeDeviceAdjustment += increment;
            }
            return largeDeviceAdjustment;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: what is the problem dear

Comment: The height isn't being applied! I've set the height in XML to 1dp, but that hasn't changed..

Comment: According to the [`Android documentation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMinimumHeight(int)) *It is not guaranteed the view will be able to achieve this minimum height (for example, if its parent layout constrains it with less available height).* Can you post the layout file as well?

Comment: should work with wrap_content and if parent allows to be such height. show layout.

Comment: Try setting it to 0dp? It should disappear from the screen. If 0dp is working then setting size code is working. Try this first and then I'll suggest something else.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is fine. Your layout likely has an issue. Did you set the layout as follows?

```
    <com.example.dynamicspacerlayout.SummaryDynamicSpacer
      android:id="@+id/betweenAddressAndTopBox"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

**See this also [does minHeight do anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408151/does-minheight-do-anything)**

GalaxyNexus Screen Shot running your code

[image]

Nexus7 Screen Shot

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:hint="Top Text">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

<com.example.dynamicspacerlayout.SummaryDynamicSpacer
    android:id="@+id/betweenAddressAndTopBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         />
</com.example.dynamicspacerlayout.SummaryDynamicSpacer>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:hint="Bottom Text"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int minimumHeight = findViewById(R.id.betweenAddressAndTopBox).getHeight();
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            text.setText("Height: " + minimumHeight);
//              text.setVisibility(minimumHeight > 1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }, 1000);

}
}
```

Hope that Helps!