# Views are not visible after addView

Tags: android, android-layout, view, layout-inflater

This is the dynamically created view:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="50dp">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I add views to LinearLayout above with codes similar to following :

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.somelayout, rootView, false);
 AppCompatTextView textView = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
 textView.setText("Text");
 AppCompatTextView textView2 = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
 textView2.setText("Text");
 view.setLayoutParams(vp);
 rootView.addView(view);
```

vp is the following:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp =
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

In some cases views are added but not visible.Even i can scroll the layout. Initial state of the container layout is invisible. I add views and then set visibility to VISIBLE when clicked a tab. When i change the orientation, they become visible. When they are not visible, i checked with hierarchy viewer and saw that child views measurements are 0. I call requestlayout and also invalidate, but doesnt work. How can i force to measure child views?

Comment: Can you pleases show `view.setLayoutParams(vp);` what `vp` value here ?

Comment: can you show your `vp` LayoutParams file?

Comment: Edited the question, you can see vp there.

Comment: nothing suspicious there, can you post also your layout file `R.layout.somelayout` ? assuming that `rootView` is `R.id.linearlayout`

Comment: @Murat, Can you remove `android:minHeight="50dp"` line from XML.. and try ?

Comment: `minHeight` is not "aplicable"/respected by `LinearLayout`, see [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408151/does-minheight-do-anything)

Comment: Initially minHeight was not used.I added it later to debug.I used minHeight to see container layout is rendered or not. By this way i can see LinearLayout is displayed or not. If the views are added and not visible, there is a 50dp height LinearLayout. When views are added and visible, its height is the height of contents. Weird thing is it works perfect when i change orientation. After changing orientation, i reopen the view, and it is visible again. Changing orientation fixes some problems.

Comment: can you post your activity code

Comment: @Pavan it is a big activity, unfortunately i cant post activity code.